# Searching for Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device b844 (rev 02) driver

Tags: debian, drivers, broadcom

I'm running Debian 11 5.10.0-9-amd64. I've got an A10Networks Thunder TPS 4435 Network Appliance with 16 SFP+ Ports that are connected to one Broadcom network chip. In the original software, the interfaces are detected, but I've removed it from the disk so I can't check which driver it uses for the NIC.

Results of `lspci` :

```
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device b844 (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device b844
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
        Region 0: Memory at f8200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
        Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
pcilib: sysfs_read_vpd: read failed: Input/output error
                Not readable
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [ac] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x2, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <2us, L1 <2us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (downgraded)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
                         10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [110 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [150 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [160 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
```

Loading the `bnx2` kernel module does nothing, and I can't find anything about a Broadcom b844 Chip. Has someone got any hint on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Broadcom page of the PCI ID Repository](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/14e4) does not know about product ID b844 either.

But it would seem that the ID falls within the group of IDs used apparently exclusively for the BCM56xxx series of switch ASIC chips. Of course this is nothing more than an educated guess.